# Is there a Fedora boot CD image on the Fedora DVD?

Tags: fedora

I've had DVD images for the last several versions of Fedora downloaded and mounted so as to serve as a local http install repository.  I'm trying to do the same with Fedora 11.

If my memory serves me correctly, somewhere in the Fedora DVD image is a minimal booting CD image which I can burn to CD and get a boot disc, capable of booting a machine and launching an install that will run off of my mounted DVD repository.

I attempted to burn the file images/install.img but this yielded an unmountable disc, so I guess I picked wrong.  Where is the boot image located within the DVD, if there is one?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware it was included on the DVD previously, but the netinstall image is available from fedoraproject.org, and the standard mirrors.

http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/11/Fedora/i386/iso/Fedora-11-i386-netinst.iso
http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/11/Fedora/x86_64/iso/Fedora-11-x86_64-netinst.iso

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using unless someone lets me know there's another hiding on the DVD.  It's what I used before I discovered the image on the DVD, actually.  The boot.iso on the DVD is actually even more minimal than the netinst image.  But it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, looks like Fedora 8, 9, and 10 have an images/boot.iso file, but 11 does not.  I guess I was the only one using it. :(

Comment: You should just edit this as an update to your question.

Comment: No, actually I should supply it as an answer to my question, because it is an answer.  People can rate it up or down as they see fit.

Answer (score -1):

images/boot.iso that it brun in cd run it !!!!!!

Comment: Where did you find a Fedora 11 DVD with boot.iso on it?  Mine doesn't have it.